# Curl request Timeout

Tags: php, curl

I'm currently experiencing a problem where my php file keeps timing out. I believe it's due to the curl code I have which is:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 600);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 600);

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

The file runs in the browser for 60 seconds and then comes back with a 500 Internal Server Error. I've looked around and tried things like putting

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

at the top of the file but it still seems to always timeout. I'm not too familiar with curl so it's possibly something wrong with what I've got.

After checking the error_log on my server, I'm seeing the following error:

```
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds
```

So I timed it and it does 500 error after 45 seconds.

Thanks

Comment: so check your server's error logs for details about the 500.

Comment: Have added the error I am getting to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7467/mod-fcgid-read-data-timeout-in-45-seconds-premature-end-of-script-headers):

That error is specific to mod_fcgid, not PHP itself. If you're using the current version of mod_fcgid then you will need to set the FcgidIOTimeout directive (ref), otherwise you'll need the old directive, IPCCommTimeout.